# Check if AWS Lambda is under execution right now using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a requirement that I need to check if a specific lambda is currently under execution or not using another lambda.

I went through boto3 documentation and found get_function() method returns State of the function, But this doesn't return function state, It gives State that if Lambda creation is Pending/Inactive/Active, etc.

Is there a way I can find out if the function state of lambda using another lambda?
Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Documentation Link
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.get_function

Comment: I don't think that is possible nor a great idea. If you really, really, really need something like this, you probably have two options. Option 1: at the start and end of your function add some code that sets some "state" in an external service. For example: you could set a boolean flag in a DynamoDB. You set it to `true` when the function starts and to `false` when the function execution stops. Option #2 is to use the Lambda Extension API to build something similar. But both options are not great. Your requirement tells me that your design is lacking. So maybe rethink your design.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement? What is is that you need to accomplish? There isn't really a native way to tell the lambda is currently executing. Anything like CloudWatch metrics is going to be delayed, so it depends on how precise you need to be. I agree with @Jens, there seems to be something about this requirement that needs rethinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudWatch metrics of your lambda function to determine whether it's currently being invoked. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-types

Comment: Are you sure that works? How exactly would you do that? I see nothing in there that tells me if a certain function is currently running. Furthermore, since a Lambda can run in a few milliseconds, I don't think that for pure latency reasons this is feasible.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround we use at work is to create a Step Function with the Lambda and check if it's running:

```py
def is_step_function_running(step_function_arn: str, region_name: str) -> bool:
    client = boto3.client("stepfunctions", region_name=region_name)
    response = client.list_executions(
        stateMachineArn=step_function_arn, statusFilter="RUNNING"
    )
    executions_count = len(response["executions"])
    result = executions_count > 0
    return result
```

After that, you have to invoke the Step Function instead of the Lambda.

Docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.list_executions